# Using MLUtils.convertVectorColumnsToML() inside a UDF?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-dataset

I have a Dataset/Dataframe with a `mllib.linalg.Vector` (of Doubles) as one of the columns. I would like to add another column to this dataset of type `ml.linalg.Vector` to this data set (so I will have both types of `Vectors`). The reason is I am evaluating few algorithms and some of those expect `mllib` vector and some expect `ml` vector. Also, I have to feed o/p of one algorithm to another and each use different types.

Can someone please help me convert `mllib.linalg.Vector` to `ml.linalg.Vector` and append a new column to the data set in hand. I tried using  `MLUtils.convertVectorColumnsToML()` inside an `UDF` and regular functions but not able to get it to working. I am trying to avoid creating a new dataset and then doing inner join and dropping the columns as the data set will be huge eventually and joins are expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `toML` to convert from `mllib` to `ml` vector. An `UDF` and usage example can look like this:

```
val convertToML = udf((mllibVec: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector) = > {
  mllibVec.asML
})

val df2 = df.withColumn("mlVector", convertToML($"mllibVector"))
```

Assuming `df` to be the original dataframe and the column with the `mllib` vector to be named `mllibVector`.